# Efficient evaluation of quadratic form for a Kronecker-decomposable covariance matrix?

Tags: probability, matrices, kronecker-product

Well, it's in the title. I'd like to evaluate $\mathbf{y}'K^{-1}\mathbf{y}$ in the case that $K$ is decomposable into a Kronecker product (e.g. $K = A\otimes B\otimes C$). (**EDIT**: $K$ is also symmetric and positive definite - it's a covariance matrix in the space of $\mathbf{y}$). The full result I want to calculate is the likelihood:

$$
\mathcal{L(y}) := (2\pi)^{-\frac{N}{2}}\lvert K\rvert^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{y}'K^{-1}\mathbf{y}\right)
$$

**What I've tried so far**

One nice property of the Kronecker product is that the Cholesky decomposition of the product is the product of Cholesky decompositions (saw this in Schäcke 2013):

$$
A \otimes B = (L_A L_A') \otimes (L_BL_B') = (L_A \otimes L_B)(L_A \otimes L_B)'
$$
So using this to get the Cholesky decomposition of the overall matrix, I follow the routine suggested in Rasmussen 2006 (Gaussian Processes in Machine Learning):
$$
\begin{align}
L&:=\text{cholesky}(K)\\
\alpha&:=L' \backslash (L\backslash \mathbf{y})
\\
\log \mathcal{L}(y)&:=-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{y}'\mathbf{\alpha}-\sum_i L_{ii} - \frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi)
\end{align}
$$
Where $A\backslash y$ is the solution to the equation $Ax=y$ (which is fast to calculate since L is triangular). I'm finding that this is slow and unstable when $K$ is huge. Could you suggest a simpler way to make the calculation, further taking advantage of the structure of $K$?

**EDIT:** It would be especially beneficial if some operations can be computed *ahead* of introducing $\mathbf{y}$. That's because I need to evaluate the function for many values of $\mathbf{y}$ but fixed $K$. Thanks!

Comment: So,  your $K$  must be symmetric, positive definite, right?

Comment: @CTNT yes! In fact it's a covariance matrix, which has those requirements. I will add that now.